# the functionalities of two lines of code

Tags: c++

When I was trying to learn from an existing program, I could not understand what the following two lines of code try to do?

```
for(i=0;0==(x&1);++i)x>>=1;


if(0==(x-=y)) return y<<i;
```

Any explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: What will the function return if the condition is not met?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for(i=0;0==(x&1);++i)x>>=1
```

Finds the least significant bit set to `1` in an integer

```
if(0==(x-=y)) return y<<i;
```

Subtracts `y` from `x`, and if the result is 0, returns `y` shifted over (toward the more significant bits) by `i` bits.

Answer (score 4):

`for(i=0;0==(x&1);++i)x>>=1;`

This code `x>>=1` is shifting the bits of `x` to the right one place. This will continue as long as `0==(x&1)` is true, which means that the right-most bit of `x` is a 0. `i` is the number of bits shifted.

`if(0==(x-=y)) return y<<i;`

This code subtracts `y` from `x`. Then, if `x` is 0 the code returns `y` shifted to the left by `i` bits.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an interview question?

The << and >> operators and & as well are all bitwise operations.

Superficially, the first one seems to shift right until it finds a 1 bit, but is destructive.

The other one is quite convulted.

However, without more context it is not clear what the program is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Will return `x` if `x` is `y` left shifted an indeterminate `i` number of positions.

That is, if `x = 01010000` and `y = 00000101` it will return `x`. There is no info in the question to guess what it will return if the condition is not met.